# Playing multiple audios at the exact same time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I'm making this app where there are multiple audios playing at the same time to make a song. Each audio has a button and pressing it toggles the audio on/off.

The problem is the sync. I start playing all the audios with a for loop with volume at 0, and clicking a button raises its volume. What happens is that each audio's current time will always be off by some miliseconds. Sometimes is unnoticeable, but most of the times at least one audio is out of sync by enough miliseconds to be noticed by ear.

I'm using the `just_audio` package. Here I initialize the AudioPlayers:

```dart
  for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      
      String name = names[i];

      nowPlaying.add(false);
      displayVolumes.add(0.6);

      players.add(AudioPlayer());
      players[i].setAsset('assets/sound/$name.ogg');
      players[i].setVolume(0);
      players[i].setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
      players[i].play();
      players[i].pause();
      players[i].seek(Duration.zero);
    }
  }
```

And `_playInstrument(int id)` is called when a button for an audio is pressed:

```dart
  void _playInstrument(int id) {

    nowPlaying[id] = !nowPlaying[id];
    playingCount += nowPlaying[id] ? 1 : -1;

    if (playingCount == 1 && nowPlaying[id]) _playAudioLoops();

    players[id].setVolume(nowPlaying[id] ? displayVolumes[id] : 0.0);

    setState(() {});

    if (playingCount == 0) _stopAudioLoops();
  }

  void _playAudioLoops() {
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      players[i].play();
    }
  }
```

All the audios are paused and their time returns to 0 if every audio is off